# Return multiple value from function in dart

Tags: flutter

Hi so i'm new to dart and I'm having an issue with returning 2 value from a dart function.

Currently I have this function :

```
  Future LoadAllData({required Map data, required String detailId}) async {
    loadUserData(data: data);

    powData = await Database.getPowDataActive(detailId: detailId);

    return powData;
  }
```

so getPowDataActive is a function that will fetch a data from my database and it will return some map data, load user data will also fetch data and will also return some map. I wanted to use the loadAllData function for my futureBuilder and use the snapshot data from this 2 function for different purposes, can I do so ? or I have to first combine the return from both function into 1 variable and access it differently ?

Thanks before

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model like this:

```
class LoadDataResult {
  final Map userData;
  final Map powData;
  LoadDataResult({@requierd this.userData, @requierd this.powData, });
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Future<LoadDataResult> LoadAllData({required Map data, required String detailId}) async {
    var userData = await loadUserData(data: data);

    powData = await Database.getPowDataActive(detailId: detailId);

    return LoadDataResult(userData:userData, powData: powData);
  }
```

and then use it like this in futureBuilder:

```
LoadDataResult data = snapshot.data;
print('${data. userData}');
```

Comment: You don't need the "as" if you properly provided the datatype in the generic parameter for the FutureBuilder, which you should.